# How to insert a variable from some premises created previously with the django query?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm building a query and I would like when the student is present and the justification is rejected that the value_x be placed, but the "Value" does not allow me to place a variable in it. Does anyone know a way to do this in django? Here's code below:

```
inscritos = Inscricao.objects.all().annotate(valor_x=(Subquery(CursoValores.objects.filter(Q(curso__id_curso=OuterRef('Turma__Curso__id_curso'))&Q(data_inicio__lte=OuterRef('Turma__dt_hr_inicio'))&Q(data_fim__gte=OuterRef('Turma__dt_hr_inicio'))                                                                                       ).annotate(Max('valor')).values('valor__max'),output_field=FloatField())),
                                                 valor_t=Case(When(Q(Presente=False)&Q(justificativa__situacao='I'), then=Value(valor_x)),
                                                                        default=Value(0),
                                                                        output_field=IntegerField(),
                                                              )
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue. To run it, just remove the "Value" command and put the variable in quotes. As code below:

```
inscritos = Inscricao.objects.all().annotate(valor_x=(Subquery(CursoValores.objects.filter(Q(curso__id_curso=OuterRef('Turma__Curso__id_curso'))&Q(data_inicio__lte=OuterRef('Turma__dt_hr_inicio'))&Q(data_fim__gte=OuterRef('Turma__dt_hr_inicio'))
                                                                                            ).annotate(Max('valor')).values('valor__max'),output_field=FloatField()
                                                                )
                                                         ),
                                                 #Regra do valor devido
                                                 
                                                 valor_t=Case(When(Q(Presente=False)&Q(justificativa__situacao='I'), then=('valor_x')),
                                                                        default=Value(0),
                                                                        output_field=IntegerField(),
                                                              ), 
                                                                                                
                                                )
```